# How to use expression results in Notebook Titles, Chapters, Sub-chapters, etc

Tags: dynamic, pagelayout

It is easy to type text into a cell and define the cell as a Title, Chapter, Sub-chapter, etc.

But I would like to make the text of the Title, Chapter, etc dynamic; the text in the Title, Chapter, etc is defined by the output of another cell.

Example:  x = 234;

Title = "My Favorite Number Is 234"

This seems like it would be easy, but I have not found a solution.  Anyone care to nudge me in the right direction?

Comment: You can always generate the dynamic content outside of the `"Title"` cell and copy it in. Or you can edit the cell at the box-language (`RawData`) level.

Comment: By copy it in, do you mean manually?  I need to generate the text of the Title, Chapter, etc dynamically.  Example: a SQL query result would be used to populate the text.

Comment: I think I am a little unclear on what you want. If you want to *programatically* generate this, then you can do so using `Cell` constructs and `NotebookWrite`/`CellPrint`. In that case you can do very sophisticated things. If you want to manually create a notebook with `Dynamic` content, then yes, copy by hand.

Comment: What do you mean by dynamically? You want `Dynamic` content or did you mean programmatically? p.s. something like: `NotebookWrite[EvaluationNotebook[], 
 Cell[StringTemplate["My favorite number is ``"]@123, "Section"]]`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just type your text into the cell, and then where you want your content to depend on another cell, type `Dynamic[x]` in an inline cell, i.e., a cell you create by using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>9</kbd>. Then, select `Dynamic[x]` and use the menu item: `Evaluation | Evaluate In Place` (or use the corresponding shortcut, which on a mac is <kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>Return</kbd>).

Perhaps an animation would help:

[image]

Comment: That is what I was looking for.  Thanks